# trigger typing in chosen jquery plugin browser test

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am writing test for [chosen jquery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) on my page.

Now I can trigger select list to drop down:

```
$('#selectId_chosen').trigger('mousedown')
```

But I cannot do the following step: trigger typing something in input to see filtering.

I tried:

```
$('#selectId_chosen input').val('US')
```

and it just paste value `US` in chosen input, but values in dropdown don't filter.

And I tried:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown")
e.which = 71
$('#selectId_chosen input').trigger(e)
```

But nothing changed on my page after this trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter is applied on the keyup event handler so try

```
$('#selectId_chosen input').val('US').trigger('keyup')
```